# In python using jupyter notebook, how do I take a 1 row that has 100 plus columns and split it into a second row using a key word?

Tags: python, parsing, dataframe, multiple-columns, reshape

I have a column that is like this: date key name email summary stats date name age where date summary age name . that continues through multiple columns thats in one row. that has no particular length but every new document starts with date. How can I use reshape or use another method to parse the row into a new rows on that key word date. I am trying take a document that is stretch in excel through multiple columns in one row and change it to a data frame with multiple rows and columns starting with date keyword as first column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split()`

for example:

```
string_data = "date key name email summary stats date name age where date summary age name date name age where date summary age name"

split_string = string_data.split("date")

for rows in split_string[1:]:
    rows = "date" + rows
    print rows
```

will output:

```
date key name email summary stats 
date name age where 
date summary age name 
date name age where 
date summary age name
```